# Is it possible to turn on/off numberlock with command prompt?

Tags: command-line, numlock

With command prompt, can I turn my number lock on or off? I'm hoping to do it with just one line, but I'm assuming I can't as that would have shown up in google.

Comment: Please remember to include the OS you are using in your question. [tag:command-line] can apply to Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD, BeOS, Dos, etc etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you search google for "utility to turn off num lock", you will get a good answer.

It is a command line tool, just a simple little exe, 'numlock.exe off'

Alternatively, there are dozens of code examples if you want to build your own application, using any number of free development tools :)

Comment: I didnt take the risk of posting the rjl link :)

Comment: It look like a reasonably legit site - there's even an address and phone number. Of course, as with any downloaded software, caveat emptor!

Comment: And thats my latin lesson for the day

Comment: I should have said so in the original post, but I'd like to do it with just regular command prompt. Sorry.

Comment: I don't understand. Hack the low level hardware with a one line command prompt? Without custom/3rd party tools?

Answer (score 2):

Google gave a few quick answers when I tried it, for example NUMLOCK.EXE and CAPSLOCK.EXE from this site:

http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/default.cfm

Once installed, the relevant commands are:

NUMLOCK ON/OFF

CAPSLOCK ON/OFF

Comment: BTW, I searched for "num lock command prompt"

Comment: I should have said so in the original post, but I'd like to do it with just regular command prompt. Sorry.

Comment: There is no way to do it with standard Windows commands. With Win 95(?) you could use Windows to create an assembler file that would do the job, but I doubt very much that will work with current versions of Windows. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151715

Answer (score 2):

For UNIX there is [NumLockX](http://freecode.com/projects/numlockx) to enable and disable numlock from the console.

Answer (score 2):

```
POWERSHELL [CONSOLE]::NumberLock | FIND /I "FALSE">NUL&&POWERSHELL ($WSH = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell)-AND($WSH.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}'))>NUL
```

Here is a good mash up for command prompt. Checks if the numlock is off, and if so turns it on.
If you want it the other way around, Change FALSE to TRUE in *"FIND /I "**FALSE**">NUL"*

Comment: It didn't work in Windows 10.

Comment: worked for me in windows 10

Comment: ($WSH = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell)-AND($WSH.SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}'))   .... you can run only that portion in a Powershell prompt (I ran as Administrator JIC) and it works in Win 10...